# anuga model asserterror

Tags: validation, testing, assert

Guys,

I installed a model called Anuga,When I do the test_all.py. there is a failure as follows.

### FAIL: test_parabolic_solve_rectangular_cross_velocities_zero_h (test_kinematic_viscosity_operator.Test_kinematic_viscosity)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lili/anuga_core/source/anuga/operators/test_kinematic_viscosity_operator.py", line 772, in test_parabolic_solve_rectangular_cross_velocities_zero_h
    assert num.allclose(u.centroid_values, num.where(h.centroid_values > 0.0, 1.0, 0.0), rtol=1.0e-1)
AssertionError

it is the asserterror, I don't know how to resolve it.

And is it necessary  I should pass all the test an validate, and then I could use the model correctly? but I still could run something even though I didn't pass all the test and validate, I don't know why. It's interesting.

Thank you very much for your kindly help.

Looking forwards to your help.

LI LI

Answer (score 0):

To get answer question related to anuga hydro dynamic model, you should mail on their user forum. They will be in a good position to solve your queries. The email id of user forum is as follows.
`anuga-user-request@lists.sourceforge.net`